# How do I solve this create react app initialization error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

Hello all I've been having issue creating a react app, keeps showing me that on screenshot above. Tried so many guides found here, not working. Cleared cache and even uninstalled and reinstalled node still not working.

Please what could be the cause

Comment: It looks like Yarn is having trouble right now. http://status.yarnpkg.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on

> tunneling socket could not be established, ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

you have configured Yarn to use a proxy or tunnel that should be running on port 80 on your local machine, but isn't.

See `yarn config list` for relevant options and `yarn config delete` to get rid of the configuration entry that's causing trouble.